# Extracting Prop from Coq to Haskell results in empty type

Tags: haskell, coq

I'm trying to make sure that a **useless `Prop` is discarded when extracting Coq to Haskell**. However, when I use the following example, I see that both `divides` and `prime` are extracted as Haskell empty types. Why is that?

```
(***********)
(* isPrime *)
(***********)
Fixpoint isPrime (p : nat) : bool :=
  match p with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => false
  | S p' => (negb (helper p p'))
  end.

(***********)
(* divides *)
(***********)
Definition divides (n p : nat) : Prop :=
  exists (m : nat), ((mult m n) = p).

(*********)
(* prime *)
(*********)
Definition prime (p : nat) : Prop :=
  (p > 1) /\ (forall (n : nat), ((divides n p) -> ((n = 1) \/ (n = p)))).

(***************************)
(* Extract to Haskell file *)
(***************************)
Extraction "/home/oren/some_file.hs" isPrime divides prime.
```

And here is what happens to `divides` and `prime`:

```
type Divides = ()

type Prime = ()
```

What's the use of extracting them?

Comment: What if you change the `Prop` to `Type`? I think part of the point of `Prop` is that two proofs of the same `Prop` can be treated as the same (there is an axiom for this called `proof_irrelevance` in the standard library). This would correspond to each `Prop` only having one inhabitant (which is the case for `()` in Haskell). I'm not sure if this is always the case. I know that in a system like HoTT, you don't necessarily want proof irrelevance, but maybe that is captured by using `Type` instead of `Prop` (or maybe you just don't use the `proof_irrelevance` axiom?).

Comment: Also, I suspect that there will still be some limitations. After all, Coq has a dependently typed type system and Haskell does not (although GHC is eventually heading in that direction, I believe).

Comment: Those are _not_ empty types, but unit types. Empty types have no (non-bottom) inhabitants like `Void`, while the unit type `()` as an inhabitant, namely `()`.

Comment: @chi Great observation. It seems that the extractor could use something like `newtype Void = Void Void` and `type Divides = Void`, etc. And then put `undefined` at every place a term of type `Divides` is expected.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Actually, I prefer the current translation. Abusing bottoms feels wrong. At most, I would use `Void` to translate uninhabited types (but doing that is hard, since we can't decide it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Things from `Prop` are propositions meaning those are computationally irrelevant because propositions are there to ensure correctness, e.g. to represent pre- and post- conditions of an algorithm, not to take part in computations.

The situation is analogous with that of types in statically-typed languages -- one usually wants to erase types from runtime. Here we would like to have the terms that are proofs erased too.

This is supported by Coq's type system which prohibits leaking logical information from types in `Prop` to `Type`, e.g.

```
Definition foo : True \/ True -> nat :=
  fun t => match t with
        | or_introl _ => 0
        | or_intror _ => 42
        end.
```

Results in

> ```
> Error:
> Incorrect elimination of "t" in the inductive type "or":
> the return type has sort "Set" while it should be "Prop".
> Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
> is not allowed on a predicate in sort Set
> because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.
> ```

A natural question arises:

> So ideally `divides` and `prime` should be eliminated altogether from extracted file right? How come they exist there?

As Pierre Letouzey explains in his [overview of extraction in Coq](https://www.irif.fr/~letouzey/download/letouzey_extr_cie08.pdf):

> Let us summarize now the current status of Coq extraction. The theoretical extraction function described in [7] is still relevant and used as the core of the extraction system. This function collapses (but *cannot completely remove*) both logical parts (living in sort `Prop`) and types. A complete removal would induce dangerous changes in the evaluation of terms, and can even lead to errors or non- termination in some situations.

Comment: So ideally `divides` and `prime` should be eliminated altogether from extracted file right? How come they exist there?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Great question! Updated the answer.